# Dynamically check difference between elements in a list

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, dynamic

I have a list containing a set of numbers in ascending order.
I have another set of numbers containing a few elements.

I need to check the difference between elements in a list such that they are present in a set and if the difference is 5 or more. I need to delete all the numbers higher than it.
Example:

> list contains {1,5,7,8,12,17,18}

> set= {7,12,21}

I run a loop in a list pointing two elements.
In the first 1 and 5. Since both of them are not in the set no need to calculate the difference.

We continue the same process till 7 and 8.
Here, I need to check the difference between 7,8 but since 8 is not in the set, I need to do increments such that the difference between 12 and 7 is calculated. If the difference is 5 or more I need to delete all elements from the list which are higher than the number from set. i.e 7

In this case elements deleted from list are {8,12,17,18}.
Only numbers below the number from the set are deleted with a condition that at least two numbers from the set are in the list and their gap is at least 5.

Here is the sample code I have written so far

`for (int i=1;i<list.size();i++){`

`if(set.contains(list[i]) && set.contains(list[i+1]))`

This checks only successive values and doesn't move ahead. How to make this dynamic?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow the requirements. Why are 1 and 5 not removed? Is it because there is no 6 (1+5) or 10 (5+5) in the list? Maybe providing an example for each of those numbers and a reasoning of why they are kept or removed would help. It might also already lead to you an idea of how to solve this.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I do not fully understand the explanation. Delete the numbers below it? This does not happen.

Comment: Only numbers below the number from the set are deleted with a condition that at least two numbers from the set are in the list and their gap is at least 5.

Comment: I have updated the questions. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below code, and in the final if block you can put the code to do print, remove etc on the element.

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.*;
        class HelloWorld {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                
                List<Integer> ScoreList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                ScoreList.add(1);
                ScoreList.add(5);
                ScoreList.add(7);
                ScoreList.add(12);
                ScoreList.add(17);
                ScoreList.add(18);
                ScoreList.add(21);
                ScoreList.add(31);
                ScoreList.add(41);
                Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();
                a.add(7);
                a.add(12);
                a.add(21);
                
                for(int i=0; i<ScoreList.size(); i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<ScoreList.size();j++)
                    {
                        
                        if(a.contains(ScoreList.get(i)) && a.contains(ScoreList.get(j)))
                        {
                            
                            
                                if(ScoreList.get(j) - ScoreList.get(i) >5)
                                {
                                    System.out.println(ScoreList.get(i)+" ");
                                    // Add your code here to remove and add it to another list.etc.
                                }
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the answer. But in my list, there may be element 8 between 7 and 12 which needs to be skipped, while calculating the gap. That's why 
```ScoreList.get(i+1) - ScoreList.get(i)```
won't work as I need to check the difference between 7 and 12, not 7 and 8.
I am looking for a dynamic way to check if element exist in set or not, not like i and i+1.

Comment: Ok, so in that case it needs 2 loops to iterate over. I have updated the answer. Plz check if it helps

Comment: Hey, thanks it does the work. But I already have another loop iterating in my project. And these 2 nested loops gonna cost me a lot of time. Can you please suggest me more time-efficient way or can I achieve this using recursion?